# Stange PRE tag (or lack thereof) behavior

Tags: html, css

Given this HTML

```
<pre>
<div class="px_xml">&lt;AddFileDialogPlaces id="<b>RVT_2016 Places</b>" delete_prior="true"&gt;
   <div class="px_ind">&lt;Place id="Favorites"&gt;C:\Users\[Px~User]\Links&lt;/Place&gt;
   &lt;Place id="Datasets"&gt;C:\ProgramData\Datasets&lt;/Place&gt;
      <div class="px_ind">&lt;Place id="Families"&gt;C:\ProgramData\Assets\Revit\2016\Libraries&lt;/Place&gt;</div>
   &lt;Place id="Desktop"&gt;Desktop&lt;/Place&gt;
   &lt;Place id="My Computer">::{20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D}&lt;/Place&gt;
   &lt;Place id="My Network Places"&gt;::{208D2C60-3AEA-1069-A2D7-08002B30309D}&lt;/Place&gt;
   &lt;Place id="Documents"&gt;Personal&lt;/Place&gt;
   &lt;Delete&gt;Revit Server Network View&lt;/Delete&gt;</div>
&lt;/AddFileDialogPlaces&gt;</div>
</pre>
```

and this in the custom CSS

```
.px_xml {
       font-family: monospace;
       font-size: .7em;
       color: #0000CC;
       margin-bottom:0;
       display: block;
}

.px_ind {
       margin-left: 2em;
       display: inline-block;
}
```

Everything works as expected. However, if I remove the Pre tags, which seem extraneous since I am setting the monospace font with CSS, then the color override only applies through the second DIV.

Now I know I could keep the Pre and skip the .px_ind styling, but I would prefer not to for two reasons. One, it forces me to get all my indents right the hard way, and two it leaves me no easy way to revise the amount of indent later. I would rather keep some spaces in the XML just to help me understand while editing, while allowing the styling to really drive the final expression, but that requires no Pre.
And mostly this just seems like an odd thing for the Pre tag do do, or the lack of to do, so I want to understand it.

Edit: An image to show the behavior.
[image]

And the HTML in situ
[image]

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce this. When removing the `<pre>` and `</pre>`, the full text is still in the colour you specified.

Comment: Weird! FWIW, I am using Safari in Yosemite. But this kind of stuff Safari has always been really good about. Only other possibly pertinent issue is this is a WordPress site, which could maybe have an impact? But it surely seems like it's purely an HTML parsing issue.

Comment: Perhaps, but it's impossible to say without seeing all relevant code then, and that would be too broad for an SO question. Try creating a simple HTML document with just the code from your question (and of course the required elements of a blank HTML document), you should see your code working as expected. Then try to figure out what exactly is breaking your code.

Comment: I do have a different result than your screenshot, other than the entire text being blue: the line breaks are gone (which is logical).

Comment: So, I added just that HTML to a blank post, and I get the same behavior. I am going to post this to the developer of the WP Theme and see if he has any thoughts. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`pre` is meant to hold phrasing content, `div` is not one of those content allowed. Browsers deal as good as they can with syntaxe errors.

https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-pre-element

You may use a browser that interprets this error as if you missimbricate `div` and `pre` and forgot to close one or both them. `.pix_ind` is then after `.px_xml` and not inside it, CSS is not inherited anymore.

---

What you can do is to remove the `pre` tag and use CSS `white-space:pre;` instead.

```css
.px_xml {
  white-space: pre;
  /* here you pre tag is no longer needed */
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: .7em;
  color: #0000CC;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  display: block;
}
.px_ind {
  margin-left: 2em;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="px_xml">&lt;AddFileDialogPlaces id="<b>RVT_2016 Places</b>" delete_prior="true"&gt;
   <div class="px_ind">&lt;Place id="Favorites"&gt;C:\Users\[Px~User]\Links&lt;/Place&gt;
   &lt;Place id="Datasets"&gt;C:\ProgramData\Datasets&lt;/Place&gt;
      <div class="px_ind">&lt;Place id="Families"&gt;C:\ProgramData\Assets\Revit\2016\Libraries&lt;/Place&gt;</div>
   &lt;Place id="Desktop"&gt;Desktop&lt;/Place&gt;
   &lt;Place id="My Computer">::{20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D}&lt;/Place&gt;
   &lt;Place id="My Network Places"&gt;::{208D2C60-3AEA-1069-A2D7-08002B30309D}&lt;/Place&gt;
   &lt;Place id="Documents"&gt;Personal&lt;/Place&gt;
   &lt;Delete&gt;Revit Server Network View&lt;/Delete&gt;</div>
&lt;/AddFileDialogPlaces&gt;</div>
```

---

**typical example to show that browser fixes somehow HTML**: when you build a table, if `tbody` is missing, browser add it and can even be used as selector in your style sheet.

```css
tbody td {
  border: solid;
  padding:1em;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Is <code>tbody</code> really missing ?</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: GCyrillus, I'll need to do some more reading to really understand all the